# Initial-boundary value problem for transport equation with $W^{1,p}$ velocity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, geometric-measure-theory

Let us consider $v:\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_+$ such that $v \in L^1(0,\infty, W^{1,p}(\mathbb R))$ and the transport equation
$$  \begin{cases}
    u_t + v(t,x) u_x = 0 \qquad & (t,x) \in (0,\infty)\times (0,1) \\
    u(t,0) = 0 & t\in(0,\infty) \\
    u(0,x) = g(x) & x \in (0,1)
    \end{cases}
$$
Is it true that $u\equiv0$ for $T>> 1$ (as it would be if $v \in C^1$)?

Comment: Why should $u$ be eventually $0$ for a $C^1$-velocity? The velocity could, for instance, approach $0$ very quickly.

Comment: @JochenGlueck We're assuming that the velocity is positive though

Comment: A positive function can be integrable with arbitrarily small integral. Your transport may end up just translating the initial data side ways by a distance $\epsilon$.